# NodeJS + MongoDB Sort Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to sort alphabetically with node and mongodb. This is my current condition, however it does not work:

```
$addToSet: {
    friends: {
        $each: [{
            _id: req.body.globalUserId.toString(),
            username: req.body.globalUserName,
            language: req.body.globalUserLanguage,
            profilePicture: req.body.globalUserProfilePicture
        }],
        $sort: {username: 1}
    }
}
```

Here is an example document:

[image]

As you can see under the friends array, it goes 'r1' and then 'a' second. Since I would like this array to be sorted alphabetically, the 'a' would go first. How would I do this? Thanks so much!

Here is my Schema for this particular model:

```
username: String,
email:  String,
password: String,
language: { type: String, default: "English" },
profilePicture: { type: String, default: "/images/talk/blank-profile-picture.png" },
pendingFriends: [this],
friends: [this]
```

Comment: Can you add a sample document from your collection ?

Comment: add some more code.

Comment: Right! So sorry, added some more info. If some more info is needed, please tell me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are unordered and for the same reason `$sort`  is not supported.

`$push` will maintain the order.

```
$push: {
    friends: {
        $each: [{
            _id: req.body.globalUserId.toString(),
            username: req.body.globalUserName,
            language: req.body.globalUserLanguage,
            profilePicture: req.body.globalUserProfilePicture
        }],
        $sort: {username: 1}
    }
}
```